# Is it possible to use the Zephr coAP API in conjunktion with openThread?

Tags: coap, zephyr-rtos, openthread

We are currently in the process of figurine out how to implement a coAP Server on an
nrf5240. Since we have experience in developing the Zephyr, we wanted to use the coap library zephyr brings with it. [Zephyr coAP API](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/apidoc/latest/group__coap.html)

However while setting up the zephyr server example, we realized that the socket structs zephyr uses are not compatible with the socket structs used by the openthread API. [openThread ipv6 API](https://openthread.io/reference/group/api-ip6?hl=de)

Going into this I was under the impression that I could open a socket with openThread and then use all the features the zephyr library provides, but have come to the conclusion that this is not the case.

My question is am I missing something? I haven't found an openthread implementation from zephyr that compatible with their coAP API.

Comment: This is a slightly outdated example but you can see how we use Zephyr's CoAP API with OpenThread: https://github.com/golioth/golioth-openthread-demo